# Как показывать картинки в blade laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, img, изображения

У меня в resourses/views/img/ хранится картинка cube.png. Нужно, чтобы вьюха resourses/views/home.blade.png смогла отобразить её.  не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Картинки нужно хранить в `public/images`, тогда в шаблоне добыть путь к ней можно так `{{asset('images/cube.png')}}`

Answer (score 1):

Не работает потому что браузер может отображать данные только из папки "public" все остальные папки для него под запретом. Картинки обычно хранят в папке "public/img" или "public/imges" и в таком случае https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-asset). Надеюсь что смог раскрыть тему полностью!))

Answer (score 1):

Папка **public** используется только для prod статуса проекта. На этапе разработки не стоит помещать ресурсы в эту папку. По сути, вы НЕ ДОЛЖНЫ вручную класть что-либо в эту папку.

Для ресурсов в Laravel существует директория **resources**, с которой разработчик и должен работать. Создайте в ней папку **images**, поместите все необходимые вам файлы.

В файле конфикурации WebPack **webpack.mix.js** (находится в корне проекта), пробросте ваше папку в диреткорию **public**:

```js
mix.copyDirectory('resources/images', 'public/images');
```

После чего пересобирите фронт вашего проекта:

```bsh
npm run dev
```

Если забыть положить изображение в **resources/images**, а в пакетах SCSS или JS будет обращение к этому файлу, то при команде `npm run watch` получим зацикленный запуск!

При добавлении ресурсов, Mix не будет их автоматически пробрасывать при работе команды `npm run watch`. Старайтесь заранее добавлять все необходимые ресурсы, после чего пересобирать проект командой `npm run dev`.

Это самое безболезненное решение для работы с ресурсами (аналогично можно сделать со шрифтами и т.д.). Для более продвинутого решения, есть соответвующие библиотеки. Главное помните, ваших рук в директории **public** быть не должно!